# Stopping Android Service while the service is running

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I am trying to start an Android Service via a UI activity button.

To start the service I use:

```
StartService()
```

And to stop the service I use:

```
StopService()
```

In the services onStartCommand() I put the following loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)
{
    Thread.sleep(500);
    System.out.println("Wake up and running :" + i);
}
```

I get an error when trying to stop the Service while the for loop is running. Is it possible to stop the running service even if it is running?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a control over the for loop.

Declare a boolean flag.

```
boolean flag = true;
```

Change your for loop like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)
{
    if(flag==true){
    Thread.sleep(500);
    System.out.println("Wake up and running :" + i);
    }else{
    break;
    }
}
```

In your onDestroy() method make the flag false, so that for loop will get break and service will get stopped.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    flag=false;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```